# Application of the Leibniz formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to show that in the characteristic polynomial of $\det (A-\lambda I)$ the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is $(-1)^{n-1} \operatorname{Tr} A$.

I'm given the hint to use the Leibniz formula for this determinant, $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n (a_{i\sigma(i)}-\lambda \delta_{i\sigma(i)}).$$

I don't really even know where to start. I have little experience with the Leibniz formula as I would usually compute determinants using Laplace expansion.

Comment: Hint: start with the product in the sum. It is a polynomial. When does it have a degree higher than or equal to $n-1$?

Comment: When we have the identity permutation?

Comment: Yepp, what is it coefficient to $\lambda^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Si.0788 Exactly. So, now, simply consider the product $$\prod_i (a_{ii}- \lambda)$$